# Out of Memory Exception while reading stream from WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

We are having 2 WEB API Apps, From One WEB API say W1, we are making call to another WEB API App as W2, Here W2 interacts with DB and gets the huge amount of data say 50-100 MB of data. This 50-100MB (`List<Objects>`) is send across wire to W1, now W1 will try to read this data from W2 has Stream and Deserialize into `List<Objects>`.

We are facing problem while reading stream in W1, we are using

```
httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

As soon as Call is made, "Out of Memory exception" is thrown. If we copy paste same code in Visual Studio Immediate Window, it works perfectly.

Is there any special feature/Priority for Immediate windows to read entire stream without any Out of memory exception.

I also read some blogs where website throws `Out of memory exception` while reading large object but not windows or console.

Any one has idea why it works in Immediate window or Console Application but no on WEB API ( w3wp.exe worker process is cause for problem)

Comment: Are you running your Web Api's on your local machine?

Comment: did you try increasing the maxrequestlength in web.config.

 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="somebignumber" />

Comment: let me try it out prashant